# Setting up a project for Google App Engine with modules

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, intellij-idea

I want to create a google app engine application with java and therefore i want to use modules for a separation of code.

I am using IntelliJ 14.0.3 and Maven 3.2.5

I would like to setup a EAR file structure for my project but creating a project by New Project -> Java Enterprise -> Google App engine results in a different structure than is suggested by this sample project from google: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java

Adding modules with the "New Module -> Maven -> Archetype" option works and creates correct modules inside of the project.

I would love to have an archetype managing the creation of the app but unfortunately i cannot find one. I read about some generator in the toolkit, is there any tooling to do this?

How do you create such apps? Do you create the folder structure manually?