# GAE multi modules (services) and working directory

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

By following instruction from:
[Create Google App Engine Project in Eclipse with Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219020/create-google-app-engine-project-in-eclipse-with-modules)

I'm able create 1 Enterprise app and 2 associated dynamic web app (default and task).  They work fine but every time running the local server (using Google plugin for Eclipse), console always display below error:

```
WARNING: Your working directory, (D:\Workspaces\GAE\MyProject\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\MyProject) is not equal to your 
web application root (D:\Workspaces\GAE\MyProject\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\MyProject\MyProject_default.war)
...
WARNING: Your working directory, (D:\Workspaces\GAE\MyProject\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\MyProject) is not equal to your 
web application root (D:\Workspaces\GAE\MyProject\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\MyProject\MyProject_tasks.war)
You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server.
```

Understand that it complain the working folder (which is belong to Enterprise App) is not same for both web root.

If I change the argument for working folder to root folder for default web app:
D:\Workspaces\GAE\MyProject.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\MyProject\MyProject_default.war

First warning is no longer display but it still display second warning.

And I don't think that is right to change the working folder to default web app root folder.

In summary, because of multi modules, I have 2 root folders but only can set one working folder in argument.  Is that a way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Rgds
SJ

Answer (score 0):

App Engine modules have been renamed to *services*, in large part (I suspect) to avoid confusion with web modules.  A limitation of the local development app server is that it hosts services within a single process, and a process can only have a single working directory.

This limitation only affects accessing files directly (e.g., `new File("path/to/my/file")`).  But [there are better ways to access files from within a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app).